# Dialog in compose shows full width in some devices

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am using compose dialog like this

```
Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = { },
    properties = DialogProperties(
        dismissOnBackPress = false,
        dismissOnClickOutside = false
    )
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
    ) { ... } }
```

This is working just fine in Pixel 4xl but on Samsung devices it's width is covering full screen. Any idea?

Comment: You are using Modifier.fillMaxWidth(). So it is expected to cover the width of your screen. What is wrong then?

Comment: But it isn't covering full width in some devices. It is covering full width in some devices though.

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual code you use in your app?

Comment: Off course I am sure.

Comment: ohh I see, because I was able to reproduce the issue when I set `decorFitsSystemWindows` to `false`, so I thought maybe there's something in your code that you might have missed

Answer (score 1):

After Android 13 update on my device, Dialog with XML layouts are taking expected width. But Compose `AlertDialog` & `Dialog` are taking up full width. We are facing this issue with Compose Dialogs only,

I am using **Samsung Galaxy M32** with **One UI 5.0** & **Android 13**, App uses **Compose version 1.1.0-beta01** & `targetSdkVersion` 33,

using only `usePlatformDefaultWidth = false` did not help,

This issue is most likely a bug on Compose side,
You can find quick fixes for both the Dialog in compose,

2. **For Compose Dialog()**

I have used `Surface` to wrap the dialog content with `modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.92f)`,
`RoundedCornerShape` with radius, set `Color.Transparent` to background color **and also set `DialogProperty usePlatformDefaultWidth` to false**

```
Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.92f),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        color = Color.Transparent,
        content = {})
```

**Compose Dialog() code snippet:**

```
Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = { },
    properties = DialogProperties(
        dismissOnClickOutside = true,
        dismissOnBackPress = true,
        usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
    ),
    content = {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.92f),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
            color = Color.Transparent,
            content = {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(color = colorResource(id = android.R.color.white))
                        .fillMaxWidth(1f)
                        .wrapContentHeight(),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    ........
                }
            })
    })
```

Check this for more: [Compose AlertDialog always takes full width on Samsung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74519216/compose-alertdialog-always-takes-full-width-on-samsung/75256622#75256622)

Answer (score 0):

There is a property named `usePlatformDefaultWidth` in `DialogProperties`. Switch it to `false` and it should take full width.

Comment: I don't want to go full width, I just want it to be like a normal dialog with some padding from sideways. And it is working fine just like that, but in few devices, it is showing full width which is problematic.

Comment: You are using fillMaxWidth(). The normal behavior is to go full width. If you want it to have some padding, you can add .padding(horizontal = 8.dp) @TalhaAkbar