# Compose AlertDialog always takes full width on Samsung

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-alertdialog

On my Samsung Galaxy S22+ with One UI 5.0 and Android 13, compose AlertDialog always takes up full width, on other devices it works just as expected.

Compose version is 1.3.1

You can reproduce this by simply just downloading [material catalog app from Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=androidx.compose.material.catalog&hl=en&gl=US).

I suspect this is most likely a bug on Compose side, if there's a quick fix, I'd appreciate it.

```
@Composable
fun AlertDialogSample() {
    val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    if (openDialog.value) {
        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = {
                // Dismiss the dialog when the user clicks outside the dialog or on the back
                // button. If you want to disable that functionality, simply use an empty
                // onCloseRequest.
                openDialog.value = false
            },
            title = {
                Text(text = "Title")
            },
            text = {
                Text(
                    "This area typically contains the supportive text " +
                        "which presents the details regarding the Dialog's purpose."
                )
            },
            confirmButton = {
                TextButton(
                    onClick = {
                        openDialog.value = false
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Confirm")
                }
            },
            dismissButton = {
                TextButton(
                    onClick = {
                        openDialog.value = false
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Dismiss")
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

UPDATE:

There is an issue created, it seems to be that this is a bug on Samsung's side:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/260755409

Comment: Have you tried adding Modifier.padding() to your AlertDialog?

Comment: Yes, it does not help and the problem is not related with it.

Comment: Same behavior with Samsung Galaxy S21 FE 5G & Android 13 (OneUI 5.0). Was correct with Android 12 and is correct with another non-Samsung Android 13 phone. Obviously a Samsung bug. Anyway, a workaround is welcome.

Comment: Oddly enough using a view-based AlertDialog.Builder works fine, only Compose has this issue. So a workaround would be to stick with view-based AlertDialog

Comment: This has started to happen on both view based and normal compose dialogs after last couple of samsung updates, same thing works perfectly fine on the other devices.

Answer (score 7):

After Android 13 update on my device, Dialog with XML layouts are taking expected width. But Compose `AlertDialog` & `Dialog` are taking up full width. We are facing this issue with Compose Dialogs only,

I am using **Samsung Galaxy M32** with **One UI 5.0** & **Android 13**, App uses **Compose version 1.1.0-beta01** & `targetSdkVersion` 33,

using `usePlatformDefaultWidth = true` did not help,

This issue is most likely a bug on Compose side,
You can find quick fixes for both Dialog and AlertDialog in compose,

1. **For Compose AlertDialog()**

I have used modifier and set `DialogProperty` `usePlatformDefaultWidth` to false & set `fillMaxWidth` with fraction 0.92f.

```
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.92f),
properties =DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth =false),
```

**Compose AlertDialog() code snippet:**

```
AlertDialog(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.92f),
    properties = DialogProperties(
        usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
    ),
    onDismissRequest = { ... },
    buttons = {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            ...
        }
    },
    title = {
        
    },
    text = {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            ........
        }
    }
)
```

2. **For Compose Dialog()**

I have used `Surface` to wrap the dialog content with `modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.92f)`,
`RoundedCornerShape` with radius, set `Color.Transparent` to background color **and also set `DialogProperty usePlatformDefaultWidth` to false**

```
Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.92f),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        color = Color.Transparent,
        content = {})
```

**Compose Dialog() code snippet:**

```
Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = { },
    properties = DialogProperties(
        dismissOnClickOutside = true,
        dismissOnBackPress = true,
        usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
    ),
    content = {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.92f),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
            color = Color.Transparent,
            content = {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(color = colorResource(id = android.R.color.white))
                        .fillMaxWidth(1f)
                        .wrapContentHeight(),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    ........
                }
            })
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer that Pradip Tilala gave works fine but I found out it has a problem. In a big screen or even in landscape mode your dialog stretches to the sides of the screen and becomes too wide, [While Material3 says that your dialog should be between 280 and 560 dp.](https://m3.material.io/components/dialogs/specs#6771d107-624e-47cc-b6d8-2b7b620ba2f1)

So that's what I ended up with looking nice and right. Set this modifier to your alert dialog.

```
modifier = Modifier
            .requiredWidthIn(
                280.dp,
                min((LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp - customPadding).dp, 560.dp)
            ),
```

with requiredWidthIn if the width of your view is smaller or bigger than the given values, it will be set to the min and max value that you have specified respectively, Which here is 280 and 560. Also because 560 is too big for some screen, you can choose the min value between 560 and some other value. The other value that I have set that looks nice is the width of the screen minus some other number for padding. Note that with requiredWidthIn you don't need to set fillMaxWidth(0.92f) to your modifier anymore.

Also here is the costume padding that looks nice for me in all screens:

```
val customPadding = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp / 6
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, this is a fix indeed. But still, having to set the width manually is an ugly workaround. Hoping for a fix from Compose team sometime..

Comment: Yes of course there are a bunch of stuff that they need to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The Alert-Dialog-Composable accepts `DialogProperties`

```
@Composable
fun AlertDialog(
    properties: DialogProperties = DialogProperties()
    ...
)

/**
 * Properties used to customize the behavior of a [Dialog].      
   ...
 * @property usePlatformDefaultWidth Whether the width of the dialog's content should
 * be limited to the platform default, which is smaller than the screen width.
 */
class DialogProperties @ExperimentalComposeUiApi constructor(
    val usePlatformDefaultWidth: Boolean = true
    ...
)
```

By default, `usePlatformDefaultWidth = true`, so the Dialog should not fill the screen width.

-> What you see is most probably a bug & should be reported

Comment: Hey, yep, it is already reported, you can upvote for more hopefully faster fix!
It looks like a bug on Samsung's side:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/260755409